# How do I fix error saying “Array arguments to GTE are of different size”?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm comparing a continuous list to see if the cells exist within a second list. It works as a single cell, but when I try to convert it to an array because it's connected to a form. Any clue how to fix or change the code to get it to work? The initial list is on the page but the comparison list in on a separate sheet called "Locations"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B100:B)="",,IF(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((E100:E*1>=Locations!D2:D)*(E100:E*1<=Locations!E2:E)*
    (F100:F*1>=Locations!F$2:F)*(F100:F*1<=Locations!G2:G), Locations!C2:C, ))="", 
 "out of range", TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, 
 IF((E100:E*1>=Locations!D2:D)*(E100:E*1<=Locations!E2:E)*
    (F100:F*1>=Locations!F2:F)*(F100:F*1<=Locations!G2:G), Locations!C2:C, )))))
```

Here's the link to the sheet. I'm assuming it doesn't work because it uses 2 differnet arrays. 1 from the Locations sheet and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OZSDju3hRyGyRfFhHJT2PLQ3DBvcfOAT1ZvNxB-J0DQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTE stands for Greater-Than-Equal, which tells me that the comparison arrays are of two different lengths. The `Locations` sheet only has 1000 rows, where as your `VirtualCourseUpload` has 50,500. Here a couple possible solutions:

- Add 49500 more rows to the bottom of `Locations` to get it to work (scroll to the bottom of the sheet), or
- Use a specific range limit instead of the whole column

Comment: Would it makes sense to add a function where when a new row is added to one... it automatically adds it to the other page so they always stay the same?